# Wifi is getting remembered and then disabled in android when connecting through my application

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am new to Android . What i want to do is that search the networks available and then on clicking on particular network A custom dialog box will appeear for entering password as its there in any android device . Now the problem is Wifi is getting remembered and then disabled its not getting connected on execution of the following code. Below is my code which executes on clicking the desired secured network . Pls help me with this

```
     password = text.getText().toString().trim();
   if(!password.equals(""))
   {
      wc.SSID = "\""+signal+"\""; //IMP! This should be in Quotes!!
      wc.hiddenSSID = true;
      System.out
     .println("Oon click to action"+wc.SSID);
      wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;     
      wc.priority = 40;

      wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
      wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN); 
      wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
      wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
      wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
      wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
      wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
      wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
      wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);

      wc.preSharedKey = "\"password\"";
     // wc.wepKeys[0] = "\"password\""; //This is the WEP Password
      wc.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;

    int res = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
       Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res );
       boolean es = wifi.saveConfiguration();
       Log.d("WifiPreference", "saveConfiguration returned " + es );
       wifi.disconnect();
       boolean b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, false);   
       wifi.reconnect();
```